# Qt C++ Add Rows to Excel-Sheet and Keywords

Tags: c++, excel, qt

I have two questions / problems.

1st:

I am trying to fill out an excel sheet that is pre-designed as a template.
I now have to add at a specific position in a (excel) list.

I use

```
auto excel     = new QAxObject("Excel.Application");
auto workbooks = excel->querySubObject("Workbooks");
auto workbook  = workbooks->querySubObject("Open(const QString&)", CopiedTemplateFile);
auto sheets    = workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets");
auto sheet     = sheets->querySubObject("Item(int)", 1);
```

then later [querySubObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html#querySubObject) or [dynamicCall](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html#dynamicCall).

How can I achieve this?

2nd:

[querySubObject](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html#querySubObject) or [dynamicCall](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html#dynamicCall)

Where can I read about the parameters for workbooks/sheets/cells to give the functions above the right ones?

I am talking about "Range( QString)", "Value" and so on.

I read the documentation about QAxobject but did not found them.
I read a lot of sites but nearly all of them only open excel, read/write to one or more single cells, close excel.

Comment: In the [`QAxBase` documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html) (parent of `QAxObject`), you have some examples including one that uses `dynamicCall()` with _"addColumn"_. I think you can try the same with a _"addRow"_ for example.

Comment: No such poperty in ... it does not matter if I use a Cell or the Sheet itself.